# df.corr() displays only 1 and 0 values?

Tags: python, pandas

When calculating the correlation of elements in a DataFrame via df.corr(), it only returns either 0 or 1? Like:

df.corr()

```
                 rain      sun     temperature   likes    comments
rain              1         0          0          0          0
sun               0         1          0          1          0
temperature       0         0          1          0          0
likes             0         1          0          1          0
comments          0         0          0          0          1
```

When I calculate via scipy.stats.pearsonr(df.sun,df.likes), it returns

```
(0.62554951411549231, 0.0)
```

Is this a weird rounding behavior?

**Solved**: pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format

Comment: Please post raw input data to reproduce your data

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to. Is it possible to reproduce it with random data?

Comment: What's the data type? numerical? categorical? string?